# After updating to 5.0, default E-Mail drains battery

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, email, battery-life, sony-xperia

Recently I've updated my Sony Z1 Compact to Lollipop and noticed that battery is drained much faster than it was in KitKat.

~50% of battery usage is by builtin E-Mail app, here are the stats:

[image: email stats]

I have two e-mail accounts with following settings:

- **Check frequency** -- Every 10 mins
- **Days to sync** -- 30 days

It also overconsumes traffic - it receives about 7-10 Mb per day even if I don't have new emails. E-Mail server is IMAP w/SSL, but not Exchange, and both accounts are pretty big (about 4-5k e-mails). Usually, I've disable Wi-Fi. BTW, firmware is not rooted.

Any ideas what it receiving so eagerly, and how to stop it doing that?